# How to deal with the registry (writes in Wow6432Node)?

Tags: c++, registry

I am writing a program that works with the registry.

Writes the data here: "Software\my-firm". Now, writing in "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ my-firm". This redirection of WOW64.

What happened - not even understand ... Nothing did. How do I disable it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396